# Android: Getting a variable from my running service

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service

My activity starts a Service, and when I close my app, the service continues to run.
OK, that's right. But when I open my application again, in the activity, I need to know the value of a public variable defined on the running Service(class) that I've started previously.

How can I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you are binding your Activity to the Service, you should have an implementation of the `Binder` interface in your `Service`, e.g.

```
public class ServiceBinder extends Binder {
    public MyService getService() {
        return MyService.this;
    }
}
```

In your Activity, create a new `ServiceConnection` class which will be used to give you access to your Service:

```
private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
        mMyService = ((MyService.ServiceBinder)service).getService();
    }

    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {
        mMyService = null;
    }
};
```

Here the member variable `mMyService` will give you access to all public members of your Service class.

To create the connection, implement `doBindService` and `doUnbindService` in your Activity:

```
void doBindService() {
    bindService(new Intent(this, MyService.class), mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
}

void doUnbindService() {
    // Detach our existing connection.
    unbindService(mConnection);
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't call unbindService, your activity still have connection to service and you can simply check the variable through the service's method.

Comment: Thanks! That's the point. I don't call unbindService. But I don't know how to call the service's method through my Activity. I've tried to use bindService and onServiceConnected with no success.

Comment: well, that's the problem. you are question is misleading. you have to ask the right question otherwise you will get nowhere. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/bound-services.html look at the ActivityMessenger code

Answer (score 1):

You could use [messenger](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Messenger.html). 
 As per android website

A messenger is reference to a Handler, which others can use to send messages to it. This allows for the implementation of message-based communication across processes, by creating a Messenger pointing to a Handler in one process, and handing that Messenger to another process.