# Can't cast to service

Tags: java, android

I have a strange problem , and I do not know how to solve it.
I want get connection from my running service.
I make this inner class with method :

```
 public class PlayMusicServiceBinder extends Binder{
    public PlayMusicService getService(){
        return PlayMusicService.this;
    }
}
```

Then i start service and create connection with it:

```
 private PlayMusicService pms

startService(playServiceIntent.putExtra("songs", songs).putExtra("currentPosition", currentPosition).putExtra("path", path));
     serviceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
            pms = ((PlayMusicService.PlayMusicServiceBinder)service).getService();
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
            pms = null;
        }
    };

    onBind();
```

onBind() :

```
public void onBind(){
   this.bindService(new Intent(this, PlayMusicService.class),serviceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
}
```

And compiler say on this line  `pms = ((PlayMusicService.PlayMusicServiceBinder)service).getService();`, that :"Unable to cast"

I have seen many examples where such actions were carried out , and no one complained about the bugs

Help me please.

Thanks.

Comment: Looks like you're trying to cast a Service to a Binder.  Do I read that correctly?

Comment: Binder to a Service, I guess

Comment: Is Binder a type of Service?  If not, then you can't cast a Binder to a Service.  That's classic OO IS-A.

Comment: What about this ?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9953326/android-getting-a-variable-from-my-running-service

I wrote a code based on that example

Comment: Don't know; don't care.  I'm not able to dig into your problem.

Comment: He was trying to cast an IBinder(interface) to a custom Binder to know more about this issue, follow this link:
http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/components/bound-services.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you add this code in PlayMusicService class?

```
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return mBinder;
}

@Override
public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {

    return super.onUnbind(intent);
}

private final IBinder mBinder = new PlayMusicServiceBinder();
```